# Strange compilation errors

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors

Could someone tell me what my compile-time errors mean and help me with them?

Heres one of the errors:

> C:\doc1\collect2.exe  [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Here is the text file:

```
 T(F)       R1        R2       R3        R4
 95.0     95.20     66.10     43.10     29.00
 96.0     96.10     67.60     43.50     31.20
 97.0     97.40     67.00     43.70     30.50
 98.0     97.20     69.10     44.10     30.70
 99.0     98.90     68.00     44.70     32.80
100.0    99.50     71.10     45.10     31.50
101.0   101.00     71.20     45.30     31.60
102.0   101.60     71.00     45.70     30.50
103.0   101.80     73.10     46.30     32.50
104.0   103.70     73.50     46.60     32.70
105.0   105.60     72.80     47.10     33.60
```

Here is my source

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void read ();
void slope(double,double,double,double,double,int,double);
void write(double,double,double,double,double,double);
double temp, R1, R2, R3, R4,rsq;

int main ()
{
    read();
    return 0;   
}

void read()
{

    ifstream indata("c:\\doc1\\temperaturedata.txt");
    int indx=0;
    if(indata == NULL)
    {
        cout<< "There is no file go get it from the CD"<< endl;
        return;
    }
    const int columns = 5;
    const int rows = 11;

    double Ihatearray[rows][columns];
    string temparature;
    getline(indata, temparature);
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
            {
                cout << "\t" << flush;
                indata >> Ihatearray[i][j];
                cout.setf(ios::fixed);
                cout << setprecision(2) << Ihatearray[i][j] <<flush;
            }
            cout << endl;
            double temp[20], R1[20],R2[20],R3[20],R4[20];
    }
    //indata.close();
    slope(temp, R1, R2, R3, R4,indx,rsq);
}
void slope(double x[5], double y[], double& m, double& b, int n,double& r)
{
    int i;
double xsum = 0., ysum = 0., xave, yave, x2sum = 0., y2sum = 0.,xysum =0.;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    xsum  += x[i];
    ysum  += y[i];
    x2sum += x[i] * x[i];
    y2sum += y[i] * y[i];
    xysum += x[i] * y[i];
}

xave=xsum/n;
yave=ysum/n;

m=(xysum-yave*xsum)/(x2sum-xave*xsum);
b=yave-m*xave;
r=(xysum-n*xave*yave)/(sqrt(x2sum-n*xave*xave)*sqrt(y2sum-n*yave*yave));

write (temp, R1, R2, R3, R4,rsq);

}
void write (double temp [], double R1[], double R2[], double R3[],double R4[],double
            rsq)
{
    //Where I will print out a table of the results.
}
```

Comment: Assuming OS is Windows given "EXE". Two things to keep in mind: 1) you're returning no value besides 0 from main(), 2) if you're using ERRORLEVEL, I find it to be an unreliable/confusing mechanism for getting exit status that otherwise requires conditioning of the environment. On Windows, I'll use the && and || CLI ops as a convenient way to determine EXE success/fail; e.g.,  c:\> myprog.exe && echo worked!

Comment: I just added this:void slope(double[],double[],double&,double&,double&,int,double&); now it is saying [Error] cannot convert 'double' to 'double*' for argument '1' to 'void slope(double*, double*, double&, double&, double&, int, double&)' can you please explain this ?

Comment: The slope() implementation doesn't match the slope() declaration. Your first usage of slope() is relying on the declared syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
void slope(double,double,double,double,double,int,double);
void write(double,double,double,double,double,double);
```

and

```
void slope(double x[5], double y[], double& m, double& b, int n,double& r)

void write (double temp [], double R1[], double R2[], double R3[],double R4[],double rsq)
```

Spot the difference? These declarations and definitions must match.

More errors, your code looks like this

```
double temp, R1, R2, R3, R4,rsq;

void read()
{
    ...
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        ...
        double temp[20], R1[20],R2[20],R3[20],R4[20];
    }
    //indata.close();
    slope(temp, R1, R2, R3, R4,indx,rsq);
}
```

Now look at what you've written, you've declared `temp`, `R1`, `R2` etc twice. Now which declaration do you think applies when you call `slope`? Here's the rule, declarations inside `{` and `}` are only visible inside the `{` and `}`.

I get the feeling you should be a little more organised in your coding. These are only details, but the details must be got right.

Comment: Thanks for the help I was able to spot my declarations and definitions, before your answer but I did not see that I declared temp, R1 ect twice. Thank you